# Wie sagt man „by design“ auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice

Wie sagt man auf Deutsch **by design**? Zum Beispiel:

> *the back cover of the CD is absent by design*

Google Translate empehlt „von Entwurf“ und „nach Design“, aber ich glaub ihm nicht.

Comment: Ich glaub Goggl in dem Zusammenhang auch nicht.

Comment: Ich würde es auch umschreiben, z.B. "Das Backcover wurde absichtlich/bewusst weggelassen"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der Google-Vorschlag klingt nach wortwörtlicher Übersetzung. Während “by design” im Englischen eine häufige, feststehende Floskel ist, kommt es im Deutschen ein bisschen auf den Zusammenhang an. Entsprechend gibt es verschiedene Möglichkeiten:

- von vorneherein,  [a priori](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori)
- mit Absicht, absichtlich
- planmäßig
- bewusst
- gezielt
- [qua](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/qua)

**In Beispielsätzen:**

> The malfunction of the device was intended by design.
>
> Das Versagen des Geräts war von vorneherein beabsichtigt.

---

> By design, the building is a typical example of the Amsterdam School.
>
> Das Gebäude ist *qua* Entwurf ein typisches Beispiel der Amsterdamer Schule.

---

> Those people are violent by design.
>
> Diese Personen sind *a priori* gewalttätig.

---

> The back cover of the CD is absent by design.
>
> **Die Rückseite der CD-Hülle fehlt mit Absicht.**

---

Ansonsten sind [Œlrims](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/11206/%C5%92lrim) und [crissovs](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/6497/crissov) Vorschläge sicherlich ebenfalls akurate Übersetzungen mit natürlichem Klang:

> **Das Backcover wurde bewusst weggelassen.**
>
> **Der hintere Teil der CD-Hülle wurde gezielt weggelassen.**

Comment: _gezielt_ gäbe es auch noch.

Comment: @Crissov: Gute Idee! Fällt dir ein englischer Beispielsatz ein, in dem “by design” am ehesten mit „gezielt“ übersetzt werden kann?

Answer (score 4):

Dakabs Antwort enthält die gängigsten Formulierungen, aber ich möchte **planmäßig** ergänzen, weil es auch üblich ist und dabei dem Original als direkte Übersetzung am nächsten kommt (der Plan, das Design).

Comment: Vielleicht lieber als Edit Suggestion seine Antwort ergänzen?

Comment: @AdamM.B. Userunknown kann keine Edit-Suggestions machen. Er editiert oder nicht ;) — Und was nur in einem Kommentar landet, geht wahrscheinlich "verloren".

Comment: Gut, stimmt, er oder sie weiß besser als ich wie das Forum funktioniert.

Comment: Auch „planmäßig“ ist eine gute Idee und bietet auch noch semantische Nähe. Fällt jemandem ein ein englischer Beispielsatz ein, in dem “by design” am ehesten mit „planmäßig“ übersetzt werden kann?

Comment: @dakab: The malfunction of the device is intended by design.